# Typecasting character pointer to an integer pointer

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a[3]={2,3,4};
    char *p=a;
    printf("%d ",*p);

    p=(int *)(p+1);//What does this statement do ?
    printf("%d",*p); //Will the pointer extract 2 bytes(16 bit compiler)or1?  

    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting output as 2 0 . I understood why the first printf is printing 2 but not understanding why 0 in the next printf ?
Is it that if I want to jump so many bytes away then I should a pointer of that many bytes long ?

Comment: Hint: think about what `a[]` looks like in memory. (Also note that you appear to be running this program on a little endian architecture).

Comment: `p+1` increments `p` by as many bytes the type it points is long.

Comment: Another hint: consider doing a `sizeof()` for `int` and `char`

Comment: *not understanding why 0 in the next printf* What were you expecting to see?

Comment: Will the last printf extract 2 bytes from the location it is pointing to or 1 byte  ? I'm on 16 bit compiler ?

Comment: `p=(int *)(p+1);` is undefined behavior (UB) as it can violate alignment requirements.  Code may crash

Comment: To answer *"What does this statement do ?"*, print the address of `a[0]` through `a[2]` and then the address of `p` after `p=(int *)(p+1);`. by my guess it is `1 int` or `4-bytes` after `p`, or the equivalent of `a[3]` (which is beyond the end of your `a`)

Answer (score 3):

`p=(int *)(p+1);` is a *constraint violation*, because `int *` may not be assigned to `char *`.

The compiler must issue a diagnostic message. The behaviour of any executable generated by a program with a constraint violation is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

There's so much wrong in that code.

First of all, as pointed out in the answer by M.M, the code will not even compile without raising a diagnostic message from the compiler. If it does, your compiler is misconfigured or non-standard. Assigning a `int*` to a `char*` is not a valid form of assignment (see "simple assignment" 6.5.16.1). Neither is the opposite, `char *p=a;`.

Even if the code was rewritten as valid C, for example like this:

```
int i = *((int*)(p+1));
```

it would still be highly questionable code. First of all, if this results in a misaligned access, the code might invoke undefined behavior (6.3.2.3/7). Second, such code would violate strict pointer aliasing and invoke undefined behavior for that reason too (6.5/7).

And finally, given that `p` is a `char*`, the code `printf("%d",*p);` invokes undefined behavior because `%d` is not a valid conversion specifier for character pointers (7.21.6.1/9).

So there's no less than **four** possible cases of entirely different forms of undefined behavior in two rows of code... kind of impressive.

---

Now, if we assume that your particular system does not have any issues with misaligned access and that you have some non-standard compiler which doesn't follow the rules of pointer aliasing...

If so, on a 32 bit system, the array could get allocated in one of two possible ways:

```
02 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 // little endian
00 00 00 02 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 04 // big endian
```

In that case your first printf would print 2 or 0, depending on system, since it points at the very first byte, and you print the pointed-at contents of that byte.

If you then increment the char pointer by 1 and somehow manage to read the pointed-at contents as a 32 bit integer, you would get the data

```
00 00 00 03 // little endian
00 00 02 00 // big endian
```

Which equals the decimal values 50331648 (little) and 512 (big) respectively. Now what you wish to prove with that, or how the whole algorithm would be meaningful, I have no idea. There's not much to learn from this practice, apart from studying the many ways that will cause this code to fail.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question about the width and endianness of `int`s and `char`s.

If we assume that you are on a machine with 32 bit little-endian `int`s and 8 bit `char`s, then it looks like this in memory:

```
a[0]      a[1]      a[2]
[2 0 0 0] [3 0 0 0] [4 0 0 0]
```

Where each printed character is 8 bits wide and each `[ ]` set is a 32 bit entry in `a`.

`p`, on the other hand, is a pointer to 8 bit `char`s. When `p` is set to point at `a[0]`, it points to the first 8 bit entry in `a`, which is `2`. The next 8 bit entry in a is the `0` just to the right of the `2`.

If the machine you were working on had a different width or layout for `int`s, then the answer could be different.

---

Update:

Here is a in a 16bit little-endian `int` environment

```
a[0]  a[1]  a[2]
[2 0] [3 0] [4 0]
```

And in a 32bit big-endian `int` environment

```
a[0]      a[1]      a[2]
[0 0 0 2] [0 0 0 3] [0 0 0 4]
```

Comment: I'm running it on 16 bit compiler.

Comment: Won't the last printf extract 2 byte from the location it is pointing to ? I'm little bit confused due to this line p=(int *)(p+1);

Comment: So, that line is a bit tricky. If it wasn't for the (int \*) cast it would be obvious that it is just incrementing p to point to the next char. However, it looks like it might be doing something else due to the cast. Don't be fooled! Due to C's order of operations, the increment happens before the cast, which is then re-cast back to a char*. So, the cast in that line isn't doing anything.

Comment: Downvoted, because this answer doesn't tell that `p=(int *)(p+1);` is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the use of the explicit cast `(int*)`, your expectation of what happens in the line

```
p=(int *)(p+1);//What does this statement do ?
```

is misguided. That cast does not do anything useful. It is as good as:

```
p = p+1;
```

If you want `p` to point to the next number in `a`, you will need to use:

```
p = (int*)p+1;
```

or

```
p = a+1;
```

In a comment, you asked:

> Will the last `printf` extract 2 bytes from the location it is pointing to or 1 byte ? I'm on 16 bit compiler ?

Neither of the `printf` statements will extract 2 bytes.

The `printf` statement

```
printf("%d ",*p);
```

is equivalent to:

```
char c = *p;        // Extract the char from p
int i = c;          // Cast the char to an int
printf("%d", i);    // Print the int
```

The output of the first `printf` call is `2` by coincidence -- a side effect of your platform being a little endian system. Had your platform been a big endian system, the output would have been `0`.

Comment: How      p=(int *)(p+1);    p = (int*)p+1;   these two are different ?

Comment: @gk123, No. But `(int*)(p+1)` is different from `(int*)p+1`.

Comment: A "*cast*" is implicitly "*explicit*". So yours is "*explicit*"ly explicit?;-) Still 1+, also for avoiding the so beloved phrase "integer promotion".

Comment: @alk, `char* p = a;` is also a cast but it is implicit.

Comment: No, that's an implicit conversion. A cast is an explicit "conversion", using the hammer, so to say, *make* it fit.

Comment: @alk, you're right. A language lawyer I am not :) :)

Comment: *"That cast does not do anything."* Yes it does. It creates undefined behaviour. `p=(int *)(p+1);` and `p=p+1` are not indentical, as former breaks strict aliasing rules.

Comment: @user694733, UB due to strict aliasing rules arises only when the pointer is dereferenced, not due to just casting the pointer.

Comment: `int*` and `char*` doesn't have to have same representation. There is no guarantee that `int*` is able to store poorly aligned pointer. Implementation could crash at conversion, and at would be legal.

Comment: @user694733, I see your point. What I should have said is *"That cast does not do anything useful."*